# Protecting my Flutter Windows app with license activation

Tags: flutter

how to apply license activation in my flutter windows app? I'm planning to distribute my app locally but for security sake and saving my rights I want to apply security level on my software product to be activated by license key or registeration key like paid application.

How to implement this in my app?

Comment: Ship it via the app store: https://www.xda-developers.com/microsoft-store-open-all-win32-apps/

Comment: Brother.. Have you found a way to have license key for the user.?